# Understanding the use of Coulomb force in the radiative collapse of the classical atom problem in MIT 8.04 PS01

Tags: charge, atoms, coulombs-law

The first problem in [Problem Set 1](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/resources/mit8_04s13_ps1/) of the MIT 8.04 asks us to prove the radiative collapse of the classical atom.

While going over the official [solutions](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2013/resources/mit8_04s13_ps1_sol/), I realized that I don't quite understand the way they used Coulomb force. Quote:

> We begin by assuming that the orbit is circular.
>
> The centripetal force keeping the electron in orbit around the proton is provided by
> Coulomb force.
> $$
> \frac{q^2}{r^2} = \frac{mv^2}{r}
> $$

It is specifically the $q^2$ bit that troubles me.

1. The problem statement refers explicitly to a hydrogen atom. Hydrogen has 1 proton and 1 electron, hence 1 positive charge and 1 negative charge. So why didn't they write $q_1q_2$ (as one usually sees in articles about Coulomb's law)?
2. Why didn't they substitute the [elementary charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge) into the equation? That is, $4.80320425(10)*10^{-10}$ statcoulombs (they used CGS units).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't $-q^2$ because we are comparing magnitudes here. We know that the electrostatic force acts towards the center, providing the necessary centripetal force.

Well, you could substitute the value of $q^2$, but that I think would complicate the calculations as it is easy to write $q^2$ than $4.80320425(10)\times 10^{−10}$ statcoulombs

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the problem... The elementary charge is (in this solution) written $q$ instead of $e$, but other than that the expression is straitghtforward.

The force is, with $q=e$:
$$\vec{F}
=\frac{q(-q)}{r^2}\,\vec{e}_r
=-\frac{q^2}{r^2}\,\vec{e}_r$$

The radial acceleration is:
$$\vec{a}=-m\frac{v^2}{r}\,\vec{e}_r$$

which yields the result that you gave.

Comment: Oh ok, so that's what I missed - the fact that they wrote the elementary charge as `q`. That answers my 2nd question. But I'm still not sure I understand why they didn't write $q_1q_2$ to make it clear that the charges are opposite in sign, just like they are in your answer.

Comment: They simply gave the result and left the calculation details to the reader. It's common. Also, while $e$ is of course a internationally used notation, you have to be flexible with notations. They change quite a bit from a person to another, and from a country to another.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for explaining. But a missing negative sign seems to be quite a significant calculation detail. Why didn't they add a $-$ in front of $q^2$?

Comment: If I can take my teacher's hat for a second: since the minus sign disappears during the calculation, I'd expect my students to simply take a pen, re-do the calculation and check for themselves. That's the point of providing a solution (enabling the students to re-do everything with a guideline), and it's probably what your teachers intended.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg: The solver is equating the magnitudes of the forces, under the (valid) assumption that their directions are the same.